# My cutom RPC meta mask created account is not showing in terminal

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, accounts, account-generation

I have installed geth and created genesis.json and run my own private eth network. I started my rpc using

```
geth --rpc --rpcport 5200 --rpcaddr 192.168.1.99 --datadir ./private
```

Then I connected to this network in meta mask and then created a new account there. Then I came back to my terminal stopped rpc and then I do

```
geth --datadir ./private --networkid 1114 console 2>> eth.log
```

then I check using `web3.eth.accounts` it doesn't display my meta mask created address. So what is the proper way to create meta mask account which also reflects in my custom created network?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. MetaMask manages the private key by itself inside the browser and only relies on the ethereum client to navigate the blockchain and to send transactions.